# Перевод из одной системы счисления в другую в WindowsForms

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть конвертер разных систем счисления. Я реализовал перевод с decimal в любую из четырех. Но как сделать перевод с остальных в остальные? Есть ли встроенные функции для этого, именно для Visualc++ & windowsforms? То как сделать такое просто в консольном приложении я знаю, а вот как тут следует сделать - нет.

Comment: Непонятно. Если вы знаете, как в консольном - то что вам мешает использовать тот же метод здесь?...

Comment: А покажите как вы переводите из десятичной в любую?

Comment: `if (dec_1->Checked == true)
     {

      int numConverter = int::Parse(enter_field->Text);



      if (dec_2->Checked == true){

       label_res->Text = System::Convert::ToString(numConverter);
      }
      if (bin_2->Checked == true){

       label_res->Text = System::Convert::ToString(numConverter, 2);
      }
      if (hex_2->Checked == true){

       label_res->Text = "0x"+System::Convert::ToString(numConverter, 16);
      }
      if (oct_2->Checked == true){

       label_res->Text = "0"+System::Convert::ToString(numConverter, 8);
      }


     }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вводимое пользователем значение является строкой, то вам подойдет следующий пример для получения dec hex и oct, при этом для каждой системы исчисления необходимо будет модифицировать поток соответствующими [флагом](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/dec/) (std::dec, std::hex, std::oct):

```
std::string foo = "0xff";
unsigned bar;
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << foo;
stream >> bar; // теперь bar хранит число 255.
```

Вот случай для bin:

```
std::string foo = "01011011";
std::bitset<32> bar(foo);
unsigned baz = bar.to_ulong(); // теперь baz хранит число 91.
```

Таким образом, вы получаете число типа unsigned для любого вида строк вводимых пользователем.
Далее передайте полученное ранее число типа unsigned в поток stringstream с соответствующим модификатором (заданным пользователем) и выведете результат на экран.

```
unsigned foo = 255;
std::string bar;
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << foo;
stream >> bar; // теперь bar хранит строку "ff".
```

Подробнее с модификацией строковых потоков можно ознакомится [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/) в разделе Format flag manipulators.